# How to clear observable properties in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have javascript code block and html like below. The model object is a generic. 
It is defined at run time.

It can be like this.

```
var model = { "xId": ko.observable(0), "xName": ko.observable(null), "Type": ko.observable("x") };
   /* var model = { "yId": ko.observable(0), "yName": ko.observable(null), "Type": ko.observable("y") };
    var model = { "zId": ko.observable(0), "zName": ko.observable(null), "Type": ko.observable("z") };  */

    var vm = function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    };

    var vm2 = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.New = ko.observable(null);
        self.NewItem = function () {
            console.log(model);
            self.New(new vm(model));
        };
    };

    var viewModel = new vm2();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    vm.prototype.Save = function () {
        viewModel.New(null);
        /*In here all of inputs must be cleared but How to :)*/
    };
```

The newForm for first model.

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: NewItem" value="Add" />
<div data-bind="with:New" id="newForm">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:xId" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:xName" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:Type" />
    <input type="button" data-bind="click: Save" value="Save" />
</div>
```

I click the add button, then I tpye sometings to inputs, then I click the save button. 
The newForm is invisible. So far everything is ok. But I click the add button again, I had written values ​​are still in the inputs. I can't clear the newForm after save.

EDIT:

```
public class Test{
    public int TestId {get; set;}
    public int TestName {get; set;}
}

public class Test2{
    public int Test2Id {get; set;}
    public int Test2Name {get; set;}
}
```

The coutn of entity classes is not clear.

My entity classes is converted json. the model is create by .net like this.
My project have a master page and subpages. 
for test page :

```
var model = <%=ViewModelCreator.Create<Test>() %>;
```

for test2 page :

```
var model = <%=ViewModelCreator.Create<Test2>() %>;
```

Comment: var model = <%=ViewModelCreator.Create<Test2>() %>; does this create the exact code above? Because that is your problem, ko.mapping will use the same observable, thats why teh value wont be back to default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

edit: Your viewmodel is a bit strange, having that inner model that is a static reference to the same observables, the mapping plugin will reuse old observables when they find them. Why are you even mapping like that to a static defined collection of observables, why not just explicit declare your viewmodel?

**Old answer**
Could do it?

```
for(var index in vm) {
   if(ko.isObservable(vm[index])) {
      vm[index](null);
   }
}
```

edit: You could also create a special observable that is clearable

Comment: See my comment to your question

Comment: Just a note - syntax error on line 2, missing a closing parentheses! Thanks for the code, very helpful with my situation too.

Answer (score 5):

You have to clear the values of the observales like:

```
self.propertyName('');
```

Example:

```
self.XID('');
```

Comment: NO !!! if you do this self.propertyName(''); you are invocking knockout observable method.
To clear it you have to redifine it like this self.propertyName = "";

Answer (score 0):

You code has some design problems. `model` object already contains observables so you don't need to use mapping plugin to convert them. I would suggest to update your code as follow:

```
function vm(){
    var self = this;

    self.xId = ko.observable(0);
    self.xName = ko.observable(null);
    self.Type = ko.observable("x");    
}

var vm2 = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.New = ko.observable(null);
    self.NewItem = function() {
        self.New(new vm());
    };
};

var viewModel = new vm2();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

vm.prototype.Save = function() {
    viewModel.New(null);
};
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3uhN7/